# Can you dynamically assign variables inside a Python function?

Tags: python, function

I have this code for a function to populate a connection string for sqlalchemy

```
def sql_path(yaml_path=None, login_key='login', user_key='username',
             pass_key='password', api_key=None, dialect=None,
             driver=None, host='localhost', port=None, database=None):
    
    with open(yaml_path, 'r') as file:
        sql_yaml = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    user = sql_yaml[login_key][user_key]
    password = sql_yaml[login_key][pass_key]
    pw_encoded = urllib.parse.quote_plus(password)
    if api_key is not None:
        if 'dialect' in sql_yaml[api_key].keys():
            dialect = sql_yaml[api_key]['dialect']
        if 'driver' in sql_yaml[api_key].keys():
            driver = sql_yaml[api_key]['driver']
        if 'host' in sql_yaml[api_key].keys():
            host = sql_yaml[api_key]['host']
        if 'port' in sql_yaml[api_key].keys():
            port = sql_yaml[api_key]['port']
        if 'database' in sql_yaml[api_key].keys():
            database = sql_yaml[api_key]['database']

    if port is None:
        sql_path = f'{dialect}+{driver}://{user}:{pw_encoded}@{host}/{database}'
    else:
        sql_path = f'{dialect}+{driver}://{user}:{pw_encoded}@{host}:{port}/{database}'
    
    return sql_path
```

Is there a way to dynamically assign the variables in the *'if api_key...'* block without having to do an if statement for each of them?

Comment: Why use separate variables at all?

Comment: For example, if you use `v = sql_yaml[api_key]`, you can have `sql_path = f'{v["dialect"]}+{v["driver"]}://{v["user"]}:...`

Comment: Also, instead of using the `if` statements at all, just use `get`.

Comment: That would make it, for example, `dialect = sql_yaml[api_key].get('dialect', dialect)`, with no `if` needed, if you _do_ want to continue using separate variables.

Comment: Granted, it _is_ possible to update your locals by merging a dict into them; I just don't see a compelling need for it -- it makes static checking tools unable to handle your code, so it's something that should only be done when you have a much more compelling reason than just a little bit of terseness.

Comment: No, in CPython, you cannot dynamically modify local variables.  You really don't need to. *Just use a dictionary*, or a `SimpleNamespace` if you prefer

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for the ideas! I see your point with just assigning the dictionary key and then calling it in the f-string. I think I'm going to go with the second suggestion. That way the variable can still be assigned from the keywords if they are not in the yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

Use get which will default to None if the key is not found

Replace

```
if api_key is not None:
    if 'dialect' in sql_yaml[api_key].keys():
        dialect = sql_yaml[api_key]['dialect']
    if 'driver' in sql_yaml[api_key].keys():
        driver = sql_yaml[api_key]['driver']
    if 'host' in sql_yaml[api_key].keys():
        host = sql_yaml[api_key]['host']
    if 'port' in sql_yaml[api_key].keys():
        port = sql_yaml[api_key]['port']
    if 'database' in sql_yaml[api_key].keys():
        database = sql_yaml[api_key]['database']
```

with

```
if api_key:
    dialect = sql_yaml[api_key].get('dialect')
    driver = sql_yaml[api_key].get('driver')
    host = sql_yaml[api_key].get('host')
    port = sql_yaml[api_key].get('port')
    database = sql_yaml[api_key].get('database')
```

OR with

```
if api_key:
    dialect,  driver,  host,  port,  database = map(sql_yaml[api_key].get, ['dialect', 'driver', 'host', 'port', 'database'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. I went with your suggestion and added the second value, so it could be assigned by keyword if it doesn't appear in the yaml file.